# Received a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null" after adding scripts

Tags: javascript, html

After adding the following 3 scripts, I got the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null". What's going on? I got these files from http://okonet.ru/projects/modalbox/index.html to add some modal box features to a web app. Thanks in advance.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/scriptaculous-js-1.9.0/src/scriptaculous.js?¬load=builder,effects"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="includes/modalbox/modalbox.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is the other code?